# file.write() not permanently writing to file python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file of names, all of which have three spaces at the end of them, which I would like to remove. When I print these names in python, I get output like the follows:

```
Adeline Panella Â
Winifred Aceto Â 
See Weckerly Â
Daniell Hildebrand Â
Betsey Coulter Â 
#there are about 1000 of these names
```

To remove the extra spaces, I wrote the following script:

```
import os
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file = open(os.path.join(script_directory, "assets/data/names.txt"), 'r')
potential_names = file.read().splitlines()
potential_names = list(filter(None, potential_names))
for item in potential_names:
    print(item)
    item = item[:-3]
    print(item)
file.close()
file = open(os.path.join(script_directory, "assets/data/names.txt"), 'w')
for item in potential_names:
    file.write("{}\n".format(item))
file.close()
```

It appears to function as expected, as the output is as follows:

```
Adeline Panella Â 
Adeline Panella
Winifred Aceto Â 
Winifred Aceto
See Weckerly Â 
See Weckerly
Daniell Hildebrand Â 
Daniell Hildebrand
Betsey Coulter Â 
Betsey Coulter
```

HOWEVER: When I run the script a second time, the output is exactly the same, and when I examine the text file, the three spaces at the end remain there. How can I permanently remove this extra spacing?

Comment: Here’s something that might be neater: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6828cdfe74564472160e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for item in potential_names:
    print(item)
    item = item[:-3]
    print(item)
```

When you change `item` on that third line above, it does *not* reflect back to the `potential_names` collection, it simply changes `item`. That's why it appears to be modifying the string<sup>(1)</sup>.

However, later, when you process the collection:

```
for item in potential_names:
```

that's the *original* contents of the collection you're outputting.

One way to get around this is to simply construct a *new* list with the final three characters removed from each item:

```
potential_names = [x[:-3] for x in potential_names]
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Python is generally considered a pure object-oriented language because *everything* is an object to which names refer.

That has certain limitations in that the expression `item = '12345'; item = item[:-3]` doesn't change the value of the underlying `'12345'` string, it creates a *new* string and changes the value of the `item` reference to refer to it.

That aspect of the language was a real eye-opener once I figured out how it works.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I am relatively new to python and assumed `item` would be a reference to the item inside the list, not a local copy of the item.

Comment: @WookieCoder: It *is* a reference to the item inside the list. `item = item[:-3]` assigns a new reference to `item`.